# Why would an APK contain DLL files?

Tags: apk

I used Archive Manager on Linux Mint to open the APK of a game made with Unity. To my surprise, inside the archive, there is a folder under the path `/assets/bin/Data/Managed/` that contains almost 10MB of DLL libraries.

The `file` command on Linux gives this output on the DLLs:

```
PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

As far as my understanding goes, those should only be useful on Windows running machines.

Why would anyone load 10MB of useless data in a 50MB APK? Am I missing something here and DLL libraries can in fact be used by Android?

Comment: Raw guess by `file`'s output: that app is using Mono and loads code via those libraries in a way like Wine does on Linux. Some comparable thing on Linux were the [win32codecs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32codecs/); also a collection of `*.dll` files to support additional media codecs on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Izzy's guess is correct. Unity is based on Microsoft's .NET programming environment. A Unity game is written in C# and compiled to DLL files (the *portable executable* format, which is abbreviated to *PE32* in the output you included). Unity packages those files along with the game's assets (3D data, textures, videos, sounds, &c.) and the Mono runtime. Mono is an open-source runtime for software made in .NET: it loads the .NET DLL files and executes them.

DLL files can contain executable programs for Windows, or Windows icon files, or compiled .NET code (the .NET equivalent of Java `.class` files). In a Unity game, it's the last of these options.